# Code generated - usleep vs std::this_thread::sleep_for

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to evaluate usleep vs std::this_thread::sleep_for and seeing more instructions generated when using std::this_thread::sleep_for vs usleep.

Results here:
https://godbolt.org/g/ZyCCmj

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{30});
    usleep(30000);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm seeing < 10 instructions with usleep but > 20 when using std::this_thread::sleep_for.

Is it true to conclude that usleep is much more efficient compared to std::this_thread::sleep_for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it true to conclude that usleep is much more efficient compared to std::this_thread::sleep_for?

No. In your code above, `nanosleep(2)` is a system call, `usleep(3)` is a library function. **`usleep(3)` internally calls `nanosleep(2)`**. So if you use `usleep(3)`, you can't see those assembly code in your own program, but they exist inside the library function itself.

However, if your program is intended to sleep, maybe it's meaningless to discuss the performance of a sleep function.

Moreover, `std::this_thread::sleep_for` is more portable, which should be preferred. `usleep()` is even marked as obsolete in [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/usleep.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can see there that you compare between different functions `nanosleep` and `usleep`. C++ STL uses `nanosleep` due to less time granularity theoretically available in its API, nanoseconds instead of microseconds.

Another advantage of `nanosleep` is that the both functions can be interrupted and  `nanosleep` would return remaining time so STL `sleep_for` can re-run `nanosleep` in a loop till remaining time expires. Using `usleep` you never know what real time was expired in case of interruption.